# Is $0$ included as an element of the natural numbers?

Tags: natural-numbers

I've seen a lot of contradictory information online when it comes to if $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and I've been wanting to know if there's a definite answer to this or not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Different choices are made by different mathematicians or in different circumstances.  Sometimes the context makes the choice clear; sometimes less so. And there are [notations which are explicit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation)

Comment: One thing is for sure: in every math book you encounter you should check what side the author has chosen. Also if you publish yourself then you must take a stand (without the obligation to defend that) and be clear about it.

Comment: Personally, though, I've never met anyone making the assertion that sum of natural numbers has no neutral element.

Comment: @Gae.S. Maybe the Romans did :-).

Comment: Some do, some don't. Most use positive integers for when they want to include and reserve natural numbers for indexing and such to avoid this I guess.

Comment: In Wikipedia, about  [Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms): The first axiom states that the constant 0 is a natural number: 
1. 0 is a natural number.

Comment: @drhab I've never met a Roman.